# VBA macro to rename multiple selected sheets causes problems with fonts

Tags: vba, fonts, rename

Im running into a problem with my macro. Im using a macro to rename multiple selected sheets. I have a collection of sheets named as number (1,2,3...50). Sometimes i need to rearange the sheetnames so for example sheet 5 needs to be renamed sheet 3. Then all sheets after sheet 3 need to be renamed accordingly.

The macro works perfectly, but it causes a rather weird problem. If i run the macro after that i try to change the font or font color (from the start ribbon in excel) it freezes and crashes... If i run the macro and i select cell properties and change the font there it doesnt crash.

If i press the dropdown icon on the fontcolor it doesnt do anything, but as soon as the mouse pointer enters the dropdown palet with the standard colors it crashes

Im really lost here as i really dont understand whats going on. Ive tried the same file on my work computer and it has the same issue.

code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RenameSheets1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NameOfSheet As Long
    Dim count As Long
    answer = MsgBox("GESELECTEERDE bladen hernoemen, doorgaan??", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BLADEN HERNUMMEREN")

    If answer = vbYes Then

        count = 0

        For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
            count = count + 1
            ws.Name = "Z" & count

        Next ws

        count = -1

        NameOfSheet = Application.InputBox("voer 1e te hernoemen sheetnummer in", Title:="Invoer")

        For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
            count = count + 1
            ws.Name = NameOfSheet + count

        Next ws

      Else
      End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: May be try using _do events_. Refer [this](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-doevents-and-when-to-use-it/)

Comment: Hello, I tried adding do events but it keeps crashing. I also narrowed it down a bit. If i enable page break preview it behaves normally, but in normal mode it still crashes..

Comment: Have to see the file in order to replicate the issue. Possible to share?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Ive narrowed it down to a problem in live preview in excel. It should be caused by a recent update. Ive reported the issue to Microsoft. Ive turned live preview off under options-->general and the problem is gone.